# countable union of countable families of countable sets is a countable family

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I study physics and have very limited background in set theory.

Let $\{U_{ij}\}_{i\in I,j\in J}$ be a family of sets. For each fixed $i$, $\{U_{ij}\}_{j\in J}$ is a countable family of sets. For each fixed j, $\{U_{ij}\}_{i\in I}$ is a countable family of sets. Is that true that the family of unions
$$\{\cup_{i\in I}U_{ij}\}_{j\in J}$$ 
is countable also? If this is true, is it related with the axiom of choice?

Comment: Maybe you meant $\{\cup_{i\in I} U_{ij} \}_{j\in J}$? Anyway, the family is countable simply because $J$ is countable. Are you asking whether each member of the family is itself countable? We cannot answer to this as we don't know anything about the sets $U_{ij}$. Btw no, it does not depend on the axiom of choice

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is indeed a trivial question.